# Asp.net how to highlight date if event is associated with a date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, calendar

I've some events for the current month and when the page loads they are highlighted. But if I change month to previous or next month and then come back to current month, the days with events are not highlighted until I click one of the dates in the current month.

I query database to get the events for the visible month if the month is changed I query the database again. So at any given time, my DataTable  holds events for the currently visible month.

I've never used asp.net Calendar control before, so I'm not quite sure how do I highlight the dates when the month is changed.

Here is my code:

```
 protected void CalendarDRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{

        foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
        {
            lblError.Text = dr["caldate"].ToString();
            if ((dr["caldate"].ToString() != DBNull.Value.ToString()))
            {
                DateTime dtEvent = (DateTime)dr["caldate"];
                if (dtEvent.Equals(e.Day.Date))
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Where is `table` stored and when it is filled? You know that all objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle? So if you change the month the page posts back and your `DataTable` is `null`. Do you fill it everytime?

Comment: Thank you. I didn't know that page posts back when month is changed. table was getting filled if (!Page.IsPostBack). When I removed it outside the if, it is working. But it has created another problem. Since I set calendar's VisibleDate and SelectedDate to today's date, if I select any other date from other than current month, the calendar jumps to current month.

Comment: @citmo09: then you know what should stay in the `if(!IsPostBack)` part ;-)

Answer (score 0):

All objects are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle. So if you change the month the page posts back and your `DataTable` is null. Do you fill it everytime?

So  load it always but assign `VisibleDate` and `SelectedDate` only `if(!IsPostBack)`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    table = LoadTableFromDB();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        calendar.VisibleDate = DateTime.Today;
        calendar.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
    }
}
```

You can also make your `DayRender` more readable with the help of LINQ:

```
protected void CalendarDRender(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
    bool dayHasEvent = table.AsEnumerable()
        .Any(row => row.Field<DateTime>("caldate").Date == e.Day.Date);
    if (dayHasEvent)
        e.Cell.BackColor = Color.PaleVioletRed;
}
```